# routing error Cannot Get /api/name student activity

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm trying to recreate a Note Taking App using Express. My code follows the instructor's example but when I deploy it and try to add a new note I get the error cannot get/api/name...I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

enter code here

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require ('path');
const express = require('express');
const dbJson = require('./db/db.json')
const {v1 : uuidv1} = require('uuid');


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/notes', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/notes.html'));
});

app.get('/api/notes', (req,res) => {
    const dataNotes = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './db/db.json'), "utf-8");
    const parseNotes = JSON.parse(dataNotes);
    res.json(parseNotes);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add at the end: app.listen(PORT);

That will work. The problem was that you didn't start the server

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work!